# Designing a Database Structure for Permissions: More Columns Vs More Rows

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

I have an application that needs to keep track of a collection of bit values that is driving a user's permissions within the application.

**Option 1**

As for the respective database structure, the first option is to retain all of those values in a single row for the user with a column for every permission. Example Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t_user_perm 
(
    UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    Perm1 BIT NOT NULL, 
    Perm2 BIT NOT NULL
);
```

**Option 2**

The second option is to have a row per permission for the user and only creating that row when the user has gained that permission. Example Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t_user_perm 
(
    UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    PermName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
    PermValue BIT NOT NULL
);
```

**Considerations**

The first option seems the least flexible in terms of growth as it would constantly require a schema, index and procedure updates to add more permissions.  I also feel that it's performance would be costly when it comes to doing updates on one permission at a time, as it's proposed, as it would be updating the entire row even though only one value is changing.  The only benefit that I see is when it comes to reading the data in the application it's one row of data vs having to look through an array of permissions, however I see that as being something the application should take on as it offloads work from the database when it comes to data modification in the table.

The second option seems the most flexible in terms of growth as the columns are fixed and additional permissions can be added at anytime in the application without having to modify the database.  I also see it more efficient in it's indexing as it's indexing based on two columns at most, UserID and PermName, vs having to index on each column individually in order to make reporting on the number of users with each permission.  Additionally it would make reporting less complex as it can just do a rollup on all of the PermNames vs having to add it as a new item to roll up for each permission.

The second option seems to be the best solution for tens of thousands of possible users.  Would there be any reason why option one would be worth investigating further?

Comment: The "advantage" to your first option will be a disadvantage in practice - you don't want the application (or SQL Server) having to serve up or parse a lot of unnecessary data. If you just need to check one bit and have to pull a fairly wide record you'll regret it in the long run.

Comment: Option 1 is only really useful if your options are mostly static, with only an occasional new permission, and generally few in number (say, fewer than 64). A binary(8) is not a large field, and reading it will be faster than reading multiple permission names and flag values. However, the permissions need to be only yes/no, on/off - multistate permissions beyond that will take up multiple bits. But since you have to add new code whenever you check for a new permission, you just need a common module to return the appropriate permissions value(s) to your app module.

Comment: If you add and remove permissions a lot, or have generic code that handles checking a new permission without writing new code for it; or want the data to be human readable; or want permissions with multiple options, you probably want to go with the second option.

Comment: I agree with @LaughingVergil id use a single field with fixed width bits. Id also add a table with position number and name of the position.